# Can I create a listener in mosquitto, bound to a device which may not be present?

Tags: mosquitto

I am running mosquitto on a raspberry pi and it all functions fine with an ethernet connection. I have two listeners, one limited to localhost for most of the functionality and another limited to the vpn ip address so that I can do some administration over vpn, all others are then excluded. The problem is that once this device goes out into the world it may or may not have an internet connection, but if the internet connection is not there, the vpn address does not exist and mosquitto fails to start.

I am using mosquitto v2.0.4, but I can update if required.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this?

```
per_listener_settings true
retain_available true

log_dest stdout


listener 1883 localhost
allow_anonymous true

listener 1886 10.8.0.100
max_connections 1
allow_anonymous true
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if you specify a listener for a non existent IP address then mosquitto will fail to start.

The solution is probably to specify a listener without an IP address (so it will bind to 0.0.0.0 and be available on all listeners) and rely on suitable authentication to limit access rather than the connection arriving on a specific interface.

If really needed you can use the firewall on the device to filter connections to that port to only be allowed from a specific subnet that matches that configured for the VPN.